# GetLastWin32Error() implementation change

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, .net-3.5

After I switched my development environment from .Net 3.5 to .Net 4.0, below code does not work properly. I think implementation of Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() has been changed.

It was returning 32 with .Net 3.5 but with .Net 4.0 it returns 0.

How can I fix this problem? Any suggestion?

```
private StarterFile(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, out bool isLocked)
    {
        isLocked = false;

        m_Path = path;
        m_Mode = mode;
        m_Access = access;
        m_Share = share;

        try
        {
            m_Stream = new FileStream(path, mode, access, share);
            m_Handle = m_Stream.SafeFileHandle;
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            if (!HandleFileIoError(error, "File locked") && error == ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION)
            {
                isLocked = true;
            }
            else
                throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That GetLastWin32Error is meaningful after a failed call to an IO function is not part of the documented contract of the IO functions, and is therefore subject to change without notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileStream hasn't changed, it still uses Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() itself to generate the appropriate exception.

What may well have changed is the *mountain* of code that sits between the FileStream code and your catch block.  None of which can pinvoke a winapi function without getting that error code to change.

It is fixable, the IOException object actually stores the original winapi error code.  It is just a bit awkward to get it out of the exception object, Exception.HResult is unfortunately a protected property.  But with a backdoor, you can get it out with Marshal.GetHRForException().  You just need to deal with the winapi error code having been translated to a COM error code, done by adding 0x80070000 to the value.  So make it look similar to this:

```
        catch (IOException ex) {
            var hr = (uint)Marshal.GetHRForException(ex);
            if (hr == 0x80070000 + ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION) {
                // Report sharing violation
                //...
            }
        }
```

Comment: GetHRForException() method sets the IErrorInfo of the current thread. This may be lead inconsistent results in my application.

Comment: That's complete nonsense.  IErrorInfo only matters to COM clients.  If you rethrow the exception then it gets set anyway by the COM interop layer.  If this is too much FUD then use Reflection to dig out the property value.

Comment: So you mean, there is no objection to use it like that way?